Did Saddam's minister Muhammad Saeed al-Sahhaf aka "Baghdad Bob" hold a press conference with US tanks rolling in the background?
A comment on reddit with 1.1K upvotes in a thread about Saddam's minister Muhammad Saeed al-Sahhaf aka "Baghdad Bob" says:

The best one was the press conference where an American tank rolled thru his live broadcast.

However, I don't see that video produced in the tread although some linked to some AP footage which however shows "Baghdad Bob" with some civilian traffic in the background and then the footage cuts to US tanks somewhere (could be Baghdad though, but I'm not sure).
So are redditors just misremembering that one? Or is there some other footage that verifies the comment?

Better known in the UK as "Comical Ali".  A Guardian summary from 2004 suggests that American troops were visible to journalists filming one of his briefings but does not say they were filmed with him in shot.

@Henry: yeah it's probably diff footage "Standing on the roof of Baghdad's Palestine Hotel, and ignoring the sight of Iraqi troops running for cover on the other side of the Tigris river, al-Sahaf declared: "Baghdad is safe. The battle is still going on. Their infidels are committing suicide by the hundreds on the gates of Baghdad. Don't believe those liars."" The AP filmed interview linked on reddit was on the steps of some building, not on the rooftop.

OTOH "But his most famous and incredible spin was his claim to reporters that the Americans would find their "tombs" in Baghdad, when US tanks were visible to camera crews filming his impromptu briefing." There's no tombs mentioned in AP footage, so that must be yet another piece, but alas the location is even less clear.
